# Find parametric equations of a curve osculating plane at a point...

Tags: differential-geometry

Find parametric equations of a curve osculating plane at a point corresponding to the parameter value $t$ is: 
$$x + ty + t^2(y) = t^4 $$
I have read the textbook and I can't find any examples.

Answer (score 1):

if $t=0$ or $t=-1$, then the curve is $$\{(t^4,y); y\in \mathbb{R}\}.$$

If $t\not=0,-1$, then the curve is
$$
\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2; y=\frac{t^4-x}{t+t^2}\}.
$$

Comment: Can you please explain to me how you got these answers? Thank you!

Comment: Remark that: $ty+t^2y=(t+t^2)y=t^4-x$.

Comment: @user142535, you understand?